# Why is vector.reserve(2) followed by v[0] = 2 considered incorrect?

Tags: c++, memory, stl, vector

So from what I understand, reserve doesn't initialize the the abstractions but simply allocates space in order to contain them. However shouldn't v[0] always give you the first unitialized memory and shouldn't assigning a value into it always work?

Comment: [`reserve()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/reserve) changes the container [`capacity`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/capacity), not the [`size`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size). No elements are constructed and [`size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/size) would report 0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because `reserve` does not change the size of the vector. It only moves the vector to a place in memory where there is enough space to allow the size of the vector to increase when it becomes necessary.

If you want to be sure you can call `v[0]=2`, or even `v[1]=0`, you should use `resize(2)`, not `reserve(2)`.

Answer (score 1):

Because it invokes undefined behavior.  The library writer could legitimately leave the address of begin()as nullptr until you resize.  Or set it to 0xBAADFOOD.  Or format your HDD when you write to it.

Now, what is more likely to happen is that this is uninitialized memory.  So nothing horrid happens, other than a pile of asserts in debug, and the fact that the vector lies about its state with no way to fix it.